# WCF low level communication hacking

Tags: wcf, security

I've just read about how WCF can send [reliable messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx#introtowcfreliablemessaging_topic1) and I wanted to check something.

If the WCF service is set to use Reliable Messaging and a client requested some data from a service.  If the client had been hacked to keep saying this data not received would the WCF service keep resending the data indefinitely? Could this be used to affect the stability of the server and is it a risk?

Are there security measures which should be put in place if the WCF service is public?

I suppose it's not much worse than clients clicking refresh on a webpage. But is there anything else which should be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `MaxRetryCount` property:

> This value, which defaults to 8
>   (minimum 1, maximum 20), specifies how
>   many times the infrastructure shall
>   retry to resend a message in case of a
>   transmission failure. Once a message
>   has been unsuccessfully resent for the
>   configured number of retries, the
>   failure is considered to be
>   unrecoverable and causes the channel
>   to fault.